# Which line in vim colorscheme is coloring my FuzzyFinder popup?

Tags: vim, fuzzyfinder

I just installed FuzzyFinder for gvim, though for some reason it's using an ultra hot-pink background color that's burning my eyes, using my favorite `desert` colorscheme.

I've looked through desert.vim but I can't find any line which is defining this color (0xFF00FF) (desert.vim appended at end of post).

Can anyone say where this color is coming from so I can change it to something different? Perhaps it is one of the "cterm" colors? How can I find out where those cterm colors are defined from?

[image]

desert.vim:

```
" Vim color file
" Maintainer:   Hans Fugal <hans@fugal.net>
" Last Change:  $Date: 2004/06/13 19:30:30 $
" Last Change:  $Date: 2004/06/13 19:30:30 $
" URL:      http://hans.fugal.net/vim/colors/desert.vim
" Version:  $Id: desert.vim,v 1.1 2004/06/13 19:30:30 vimboss Exp $

" cool help screens
" :he group-name
" :he highlight-groups
" :he cterm-colors

set background=dark
if version > 580
    " no guarantees for version 5.8 and below, but this makes it stop
    " complaining
    hi clear
    if exists("syntax_on")
    syntax reset
    endif
endif
let g:colors_name="desert"

hi Normal   guifg=White guibg=grey20

" highlight groups
hi Cursor   guibg=khaki guifg=slategrey
"hi CursorIM
"hi Directory
"hi DiffAdd
"hi DiffChange
"hi DiffDelete
"hi DiffText
"hi ErrorMsg
hi VertSplit    guibg=#c2bfa5 guifg=grey50 gui=none
hi Folded   guibg=grey30 guifg=gold
hi FoldColumn   guibg=grey30 guifg=tan
hi IncSearch    guifg=slategrey guibg=khaki
"hi LineNr
hi ModeMsg  guifg=goldenrod
hi MoreMsg  guifg=SeaGreen
hi NonText  guifg=LightBlue guibg=grey30
hi Question guifg=springgreen
hi Search   guibg=peru guifg=wheat
hi SpecialKey   guifg=yellowgreen
hi StatusLine   guibg=#c2bfa5 guifg=black gui=none
hi StatusLineNC guibg=#c2bfa5 guifg=grey50 gui=none
hi Title    guifg=indianred
hi Visual   gui=none guifg=khaki guibg=olivedrab
"hi VisualNOS
hi WarningMsg   guifg=salmon
"hi WildMenu
"hi Menu
"hi Scrollbar
"hi Tooltip

" syntax highlighting groups
hi Comment  guifg=SkyBlue
hi Constant guifg=#ffa0a0
hi Identifier   guifg=palegreen
hi Statement    guifg=khaki
hi PreProc  guifg=indianred
hi Type     guifg=darkkhaki
hi Special  guifg=navajowhite
"hi Underlined
hi Ignore   guifg=grey40
"hi Error
hi Todo     guifg=orangered guibg=yellow2

" color terminal definitions
hi SpecialKey   ctermfg=darkgreen
hi NonText  cterm=bold ctermfg=darkblue
hi Directory    ctermfg=darkcyan
hi ErrorMsg cterm=bold ctermfg=7 ctermbg=1
hi IncSearch    cterm=NONE ctermfg=yellow ctermbg=green
hi Search   cterm=NONE ctermfg=grey ctermbg=blue
hi MoreMsg  ctermfg=darkgreen
hi ModeMsg  cterm=NONE ctermfg=brown
hi LineNr   ctermfg=3
hi Question ctermfg=green
hi StatusLine   cterm=bold,reverse
hi StatusLineNC cterm=reverse
hi VertSplit    cterm=reverse
hi Title    ctermfg=5
hi Visual   cterm=reverse
hi VisualNOS    cterm=bold,underline
hi WarningMsg   ctermfg=1
hi WildMenu ctermfg=0 ctermbg=3
hi Folded   ctermfg=darkgrey ctermbg=NONE
hi FoldColumn   ctermfg=darkgrey ctermbg=NONE
hi DiffAdd  ctermbg=4
hi DiffChange   ctermbg=5
hi DiffDelete   cterm=bold ctermfg=4 ctermbg=6
hi DiffText cterm=bold ctermbg=1
hi Comment  ctermfg=darkcyan
hi Constant ctermfg=brown
hi Special  ctermfg=5
hi Identifier   ctermfg=6
hi Statement    ctermfg=3
hi PreProc  ctermfg=5
hi Type     ctermfg=2
hi Underlined   cterm=underline ctermfg=5
hi Ignore   cterm=bold ctermfg=7
hi Ignore   ctermfg=darkgrey
hi Error    cterm=bold ctermfg=7 ctermbg=1


"vim: sw=4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using

> Pmenu    Popup menu: normal item

```
:hi Pmenu ctermbg=red  "for vim
:hi Pmenu guibg=red    "for gvim
```

Comment: Thanks for leading me to Pmenu, but it turned out that I need to use guibg and not ctermbg. Maybe it's because I'm using gvim instead of vim (should have made it more clear in the question title).